# PHP Function error in live server but not in my local machine

Tags: php, wordpress

The platform we're using is wordpress. Wordpress is working in the live server. I'm trying to get it to work on my local machine.

It gives me this error when I replace the files of wordpress in my local machine

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in C:\wamp\www\mywordpressdirectory\wp-content\mu-plugins\wpengine-common\plugin.php on line 788

This line has this function

```
public function disable_indiv_plugin_update_notices( $value ) {
    $plugins_to_disable_notices_for = array();
    $basename = '';
    foreach ($plugins_to_disable_notices_for as $plugin) {
        $basename = plugin_basename( $plugin );
    }
    if (isset($value->response[@$basename])) {
        unset( $value->response[$basename] );
    }
    return $value;
}
```

I don't find any wrong with that function though. The above before this function is

```
function wpengine_credits() {
    if (get_option('stylesheet') != 'twentyeleven' && get_option('template') != 'twentyeleven') {
        return false;
    }
    if (!defined('WPE_FOOTER_HTML') OR !WPE_FOOTER_HTML OR $this->already_emitted_powered_by == true) {
        return false;
    }
    //to prevent repeating
    $this->already_emitted_powered_by = true; ?>
    <div id="site-host">
            WP Engine <a href="http://wpengine.com" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Managed WordPress Hosting', 'wpengine' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( '%s.', 'wpengine' ), 'WordPress Hosting' ); ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Also the live production server is using 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 while my local work station is 5.5.12

Answer (score 0):

`unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)` gives away the problem.

```
public function disable_indiv_plugin_update_notices( $value ) {
```

should probably be

```
function disable_indiv_plugin_update_notices( $value ) {
```

Unless the function is in a class, the keywords `public`, `protected`, and `private` aren't needed (and will break the parser).